# Samsung S5 and Note 4 July security update appears to have broken BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, samsung-galaxy

I'm looking for help finding a workaround for an issue that appears to be a problem with a recent security update for the Samsung S5 and Note 4 devices causing BLE device to not connect. The update was distributed by Verizon in early August and the Security Update date is: July 1, 2017 with a build number ending in DQF2. We are unable to connect to our BLE devices from the phones that have this specific update.

The BLE connection is made after scanning and finding the device. The scan works fine and devices are found normally but the connection goes nowhere. It's done like this:

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBtAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
device.connectGatt(context, true, btGattCallback);
```

However, I do not get any update from the callback is never notified of a connection with autoConnect = true, and with autoConnect = false, the callback only gets a connection update saying it disconnected (never gets to a connected state).

Before this update the connection was very reliable but fails 100% of the time since that update. Even a hard reset of the phone and BLE device and it still won't connect as well.

I've experimented with different things like making the connection on the main thread, ensuring that BLE scanning has stopped before connecting (we do this already but I added some extra delay as well in case of a race condition). I've added delays in different parts and experimented with both autoConnect on and off and no luck so far.

This definitely seems to be an issue with Samsung and I can see that the [FitBit forums are lit up with users having this issue](https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Android-App/Fitbit-trackers-not-syncing-after-Android-software-update-8-8/td-p/2134240) and while our product doesn't have as large of a base as FitBit it is effecting many people.

The only thing interesting I could find from logcat included:

```
08-12 14:11:17.848 4412-4602/? D/bt_upio: upio_set : pio 0 action 2, polarity 1
08-12 14:11:17.848 4412-4602/? D/bt_upio: BT_WAKE is asserted already
08-12 14:11:17.848 4412-4597/? D/BtGatt.GattService: [GSIM LOG]: increaseScanCount 4 Battery : com.myapp.internal.debug : 7
08-12 14:11:17.858 4412-4556/? D/bt_btif_gattc: btif_gattc_update_properties BLE device name=Axon-X81001976 len=14 dev_type=2
08-12 14:11:17.858 4412-4556/? E/bt_btif: property type:241, len:0 is invalid
08-12 14:11:17.858 4412-4556/? E/bt_btif_dm: ### ASSERT : system/bt/main/../btif/src/btif_dm.c line 4655 failed to save remote device manufacturer (1) ###
```

Other related threads:

- [VZW S5 thread](https://community.verizonwireless.com/thread/936098)
- [VZW Note 5 thread](https://community.verizonwireless.com/thread/936180)
- [Samsung Developer thread](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=316692&startId=zzzzz~&searchType=ALL&searchText=bluetooth)
- [Square contactless reader thread](https://www.sellercommunity.com/t5/Troubleshooting/Verizon-Phone-Not-Syncing-with-Contactless-and-Chip-Card-Reader/m-p/45838#M6967)

Has anyone identified a way to make valid BLE connections on these devices?

Comment: Um, at the risk of sounding like Alex Trebek, could you please phrase this in the form of a question? What specific *programming* question are you looking to have answered here?

Comment: First sentence. A recent security update from samsung appears to have botched BLE and potentially hundreds of thousands of people are being effected but there's little to nothing on the internet except device forums. Figured it'd be good to add a thread here in case a developer has found a workaround.

Comment: Your first sentence is not a question. I have appended what I think your question is to the bottom, but I am not completely certain if that is what you are asking Stack Overflow contributors to answer.

Comment: Interesting... Do you see any particular error in the Logcat outputs from the Bluetooth stack?

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: @MattWolfe I noticed that connections seem to work while the scan is still active. Can you confirm that?